# foreach over array and get values with php

Tags: php, arrays

using jquery's .post i send do my php code an object that with `var_dump` i get this result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00176 "]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00171 "]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00173 "]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00177 "]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00183 "]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["00149 "]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

how can i get values from this array? i would like to

```
foreach{
echo $key . '__ ' . $value //would give for [0]: '00176 __ 2'
}
```

how can i achieve that?

Comment: You just get it from the array. I mean, that's a standard array, you just get it. Where do you in concrete hit the road block? You're new to PHP arrays or [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)?

Comment: yes, i am very very newbie.... so thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are struggling with the nested structure of the array, you can flatten it first and then just do the `foreach`:

```
// flatten the array:
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

// standard foreach:
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
   echo $key . '__ ' . $value;
}
```

Another alternative is to use [`each`](http://php.net/each):

```
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    list($key, $value) = each($entry);
    echo $key . '__ ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need and outer and an inner loop due to the key values changing of the sub array. I would look to restructure your post data a bit cleaner.

```
foreach($array as $item)
{
  if(is_array($item))
    foreach($item as $key => $value)
    {
      echo $key . '__ ' . $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving a multi-dimensional array by POST, it has this structure:

```
$_POST[0][00176] = '2'
$_POST[1][00171] = '5'
$_POST[2][00173] = '1'
$_POST[3][00177] = '4'
$_POST[4][00183] = '2'
$_POST[5][00149] = '1'
```

So i think the easier way to read it as you want is doing a foreach inside another foreach, like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        echo $key2 . '__' . $value2;
    }

}
```

In PHP docs there is a example of reading multi-dimensional arrays using [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)